# How do I manage one product with multiple vendors in Magento for same store?

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.8

Suppose there are multiple vendors for the same product (say a mobile phone of a xyz brand/model).

One product but multiple vendors.

Is it possible to list all the vendors on the product page for that particular product?